# How do I create a generated scan report for PDF in Arachni Web Application Security Scanner Framework?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, lib, penetration-testing

I have been working on a project where I have to modify the Arachni Web Application Security Scanner Framework and get it to generate and download a scan report in PDF format. The web application itself is powered by Ruby on Rails. Here is the link to the application that I am talking about.

https://www.arachni-scanner.com/

Now, the default application generates five file formats: HTML (or HTML.zip), JSON, Marshal, YAML, and XML. I am trying to include PDF, and the PDF report has to look exactly like the contents of the HTML report, charts and all. The application folder has its own libraries directory. There is one library called Arachni-1.5.1, and I have come to the conclusion that it is the heart of where the generated file formats are being made. I can give one example, specifically the library file that supposedly creates the HTML.zip report. It is code in the Arachni-1.5.1 library under a folder called reporters, and the name of the file is html.rb.

`module TemplateUtilities

```
    def base64_encode( string )
        Base64.encode64( string ).gsub( /\n/, '' )
    end

    def normalize( str )
        str.to_s.recode
    end

    def md( markdown )
        html = Kramdown::Document.new( markdown ).to_html.recode
        Loofah.fragment( html ).scrub!(:prune).to_s
    end

    def key_to_words( k )
        k.to_s.capitalize.gsub( '_', ' ' )
    end

    def code_highlight( code, language = :html, options = {} )
        return if !code

        lines = CodeRay.scan( code.recode, language ).
            html( css: :style ).lines.to_a

        if options[:from]
            from = [0, options[:from]].max
        else
            from = 0
        end

        if options[:to]
            to = [lines.size, options[:to]].min
        else
            to = lines.size - 1
        end

        code = '<div class="code-container"><table class="CodeRay"><tbody><tr><td class="line-numbers"><pre>'

        from.upto(to) do |i|
            if options[:anchor_id]
                line = "<a href='#{id_to_location "#{options[:anchor_id]}-#{i}"}'>#{i}</a>"
            else
                line = "#{i}"
            end

            if options[:breakpoint] && options[:breakpoint] == i
                code << "<span class='breakpoint'>#{line}</span>"
            else
                code << line
            end

            code << "\n"
        end

        code << '</pre></td><td class="code"><pre>'

        from.upto(to) do |i|
            line = "<span id='#{options[:anchor_id]}-#{i}'>#{lines[i]}</span>"

            if options[:breakpoint] && options[:breakpoint] == i
                code << "<span class='breakpoint'>#{line}</span>"
            else
                code << line.to_s
            end
        end

        code + '</pre></td></tr></tbody></table></div>'
    end

    def highlight_proof( string, proof )
        proof  = proof.to_s.recode
        string = string.to_s.recode

        return escapeHTML( string ) if proof.to_s.empty?
        return escapeHTML( string ) if !string.include?( proof )

        escaped_proof         = escapeHTML( proof )
        escaped_response_body = escapeHTML( string )

        escaped_response_body.gsub(
            escaped_proof,
            "<span class=\"issue-proof-highlight\">#{escaped_proof}</span>"
        )
    end

    def data_dump( data )
        ap = AwesomePrint::Inspector.new( plain: true, html: true )
        "<pre class='data-dump'>#{ap.awesome( data )}</pre>"
    end

    # Carefully escapes HTML and converts to UTF-8 while removing
    # invalid character sequences.
    def escapeHTML( str )
        CGI.escapeHTML( normalize( str ) )
    end

    def highlight_issue_page_body( issue, span_class )
        return escapeHTML( issue.page.body ) if !issue.page.body.include?( issue.proof )

        escaped_proof         = escapeHTML( issue.proof )
        escaped_response_body = escapeHTML( issue.page.body )

        escaped_response_body.gsub(
            escaped_proof,
            "<span class=\"#{span_class}\">#{escaped_proof}</span>"
        )
    end

    def issue_location( issue )
        id_to_location( issue_id( issue ) )
    end

    def issue_id( issue )
        issue = report.issue_by_digest( issue.digest )

        "issues-#{'un' if issue.untrusted?}trusted-severity-" <<
            "#{issue.severity}-#{issue.check[:shortname]}-#{issue.digest}"
    end

    def id_to_location( id )
        "#!/#{id.gsub( '-', '/' )}"
    end

    def erb( tpl, params = {} )
        scope = TemplateScope.new( params )

        tpl = tpl.to_s + '.erb' if tpl.is_a?( Symbol )

        path = File.exist?( tpl ) ? tpl : TEMPLATE_DIR + tpl

        ERB.new( IO.read( path ).recode ).result( scope.get_binding )
    rescue
        ap tpl
        raise
    end
end

include TemplateUtilities

class TemplateScope
    include TemplateUtilities

    ISSUES_URL = 'https://github.com/Arachni/arachni/issues'

    def initialize( params = {} )
        update params
        update self.class.global_data
    end

    def update( params )
        params.each { |name, value| self[name] = value }
        self
    end

    def []=( name, value )
        self.class.send( :attr_accessor, name )
        instance_variable_set( "@#{name.to_s}", value )
        self
    end

    def prep_description( str )
        escapeHTML Arachni::Reporters::HTML.prep_description( str )
    end

    def get_plugin_info( name )
        report.plugins[name.to_sym]
    end

    def js_multiline( str )
        "\"" + normalize( str ).gsub( "\n", '\n' ) + "\""
    end

    def get_binding
        binding
    end

    def self.global_data=( data )
        @global_data = data
    end

    def self.global_data
        @global_data
    end
end

def global_data
    grouped_issues = {
        trusted:   {},
        untrusted: {}
    }

    Arachni::Issue::Severity::ORDER.each do |severity|
        by_severity = report.issues.select { |i| i.severity.to_sym == severity }
        next if by_severity.empty?

        by_name = {}
        by_severity.each do |issue|
            by_name[issue.name] ||= []
            by_name[issue.name] << issue
        end
        next if by_name.empty?

        grouped_issues[:trusted][by_severity.first.severity] =
            by_name.inject({}) do |h, (name, issues)|
                i = issues.select(&:trusted?)
                next h if i.empty?

                h[name] = i
                h
            end

        grouped_issues[:untrusted][by_severity.first.severity] =
            by_name.inject({}) do |h, (name, issues)|
                i = issues.select(&:untrusted?)
                next h if i.empty?

                h[name] = i
                h
            end

        [:trusted, :untrusted].each do |t|
            if grouped_issues[t][by_severity.first.severity].empty?
                grouped_issues[t].delete by_severity.first.severity
            end
        end
    end

    [:trusted, :untrusted].each do |t|
        grouped_issues.delete( t ) if grouped_issues[t].empty?
    end

    prepare_data.merge(
        report:         report,
        grouped_issues: grouped_issues,
        plugins:        format_plugin_results
    )
end

# Runs the HTML report.
def run
    FileUtils.rm_rf outfile

    print_line
    print_status 'Creating HTML report...'

    TemplateScope.global_data = global_data

    tmpdir = "#{Arachni::Options.paths.tmpdir}/#{generate_token}/"

    FileUtils.rm_rf tmpdir
    FileUtils.mkdir_p tmpdir

    FileUtils.mkdir_p "#{tmpdir}/js/lib"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p "#{tmpdir}/css/lib"

    FileUtils.cp_r "#{TEMPLATE_DIR}/fonts", "#{tmpdir}/"
    FileUtils.cp_r "#{TEMPLATE_DIR}/js/lib", "#{tmpdir}/js/"
    FileUtils.cp_r "#{TEMPLATE_DIR}/css/lib", "#{tmpdir}/css/"

    %w(js/helpers.js js/init.js.erb js/charts.js.erb js/configuration.js.erb
        css/main.css).each do |f|
        if f.end_with? '.erb'
            IO.write( "#{tmpdir}/#{f.split('.erb').first}", erb( "#{TEMPLATE_DIR}/#{f}" ) )
        else
            FileUtils.cp( "#{TEMPLATE_DIR}/#{f}" , "#{tmpdir}/#{f}" )
        end
    end

    IO.write( "#{tmpdir}/index.html", erb( TEMPLATE_FILE ) )

    compress( tmpdir, outfile )
    FileUtils.rm_rf tmpdir

    print_status "Saved in '#{outfile}'."
end

def self.info
    {
        name:         'HTML',
        description:  %q{Exports the audit results as a compressed HTML report.},
        content_type: 'application/zip',
        author:       'Tasos "Zapotek" Laskos <tasos.laskos@arachni-scanner.com>',
        version:      '0.4.3',
        options:      [
            Options.outfile( '.html.zip' ),
            Options.skip_responses
        ]
    }
end

private

def compress( directory, archive )
    Zip::File.open( archive, Zip::File::CREATE ) do |zipfile|
        Dir[File.join(directory, '**', '**')].each do |file|
            zipfile.add( file.sub( directory, '' ), file )
        end
    end

    archive
end

def self.prep_description( str )
    placeholder =  '--' + rand( 1000 ).to_s + '--'
    cstr = str.gsub( /^\s*$/xm, placeholder )
    cstr.gsub!( /^\s*/xm, '' )
    cstr.gsub!( placeholder, "\n" )
    cstr.chomp
end

def prepare_data
    graph_data = {
        severities:       {
            Severity::HIGH.to_sym          => 0,
            Severity::MEDIUM.to_sym        => 0,
            Severity::LOW.to_sym           => 0,
            Severity::INFORMATIONAL.to_sym => 0
        },
        severity_for_issue: {},
        severity_index_for_issue: {},
        severity_regions: {},
        issues:           {},
        issues_shortnames: Set.new,
        trusted_issues:   {},
        untrusted_issues: {},
        elements:         {
            Element::Form.type   => 0,
            Element::Form::DOM.type   => 0,
            Element::Link.type   => 0,
            Element::Link::DOM.type   => 0,
            Element::Cookie.type => 0,
            Element::Cookie::DOM.type => 0,
            Element::LinkTemplate.type => 0,
            Element::LinkTemplate::DOM.type => 0,
            Element::Header.type => 0,
            Element::Body.type   => 0,
            Element::Path.type   => 0,
            Element::Server.type => 0,
            Element::GenericDOM.type  => 0,
            Element::JSON.type        => 0,
            Element::XML.type         => 0,
            Element::UIInput::DOM.type  => 0,
            Element::UIForm::DOM.type => 0
        },
        verification:     {
            'Yes' => 0,
            'No'  => 0
        },
        trust:            {
            'Trusted'   => 0,
            'Untrusted' => 0
        }
    }

    total_severities = 0
    total_elements   = 0

    has_trusted_issues   = false
    has_untrusted_issues = false
    last_severity        = nil

    report.issues.each.with_index do |issue, i|
        graph_data[:severities][issue.severity.to_sym] += 1
        total_severities += 1

        graph_data[:issues][issue.name] ||= 0
        graph_data[:issues][issue.name] += 1

        graph_data[:elements][issue.vector.class.type] += 1
        total_elements += 1

        verification = issue.untrusted? ? 'Yes' : 'No'
        graph_data[:verification][verification] += 1

        graph_data[:untrusted_severities] ||= {}
        graph_data[:untrusted_severities][issue.severity.to_sym] ||= 0

        graph_data[:trusted_severities] ||= {}
        graph_data[:trusted_severities][issue.severity.to_sym] ||= 0

        graph_data[:trusted_issues][issue.name]   ||= 0
        graph_data[:untrusted_issues][issue.name] ||= 0

        graph_data[:issues_shortnames] << issue.check[:shortname]
        graph_data[:severity_for_issue][issue.check[:shortname]] = issue.severity.to_s

        new_region = !graph_data[:severity_regions].include?( issue.severity.to_sym )

        graph_data[:severity_regions][issue.severity.to_sym] ||= {}
        graph_data[:severity_regions][issue.severity.to_sym][:class]  =
            "severity-#{issue.severity.to_sym}"
        graph_data[:severity_regions][issue.severity.to_sym][:start] ||=
            graph_data[:issues].size - 1

        if new_region && last_severity
            graph_data[:severity_regions][last_severity][:end] =
                graph_data[:issues].size - 2
        end
        last_severity = issue.severity.to_sym

        graph_data[:severity_index_for_issue][issue.name] =
            Issue::Severity::ORDER.reverse.index( issue.severity.to_sym ) + 1

        if issue.trusted?
            has_trusted_issues = true
            graph_data[:trust]['Trusted'] += 1
            graph_data[:trusted_severities][issue.severity.to_sym] += 1
            graph_data[:trusted_issues][issue.name] += 1
        else
            has_untrusted_issues = true
            graph_data[:trust]['Untrusted'] += 1
            graph_data[:untrusted_severities][issue.severity.to_sym] += 1
            graph_data[:untrusted_issues][issue.name]  += 1
        end
    end

    graph_data[:issues_shortnames] = graph_data[:issues_shortnames].to_a
    graph_data[:severity_regions]  = graph_data[:severity_regions].values

    {
        graph_data:           graph_data,
        total_severities:     total_severities,
        total_elements:       total_elements,
        has_trusted_issues:   has_trusted_issues,
        has_untrusted_issues: has_untrusted_issues
    }
end`
```

Now, how would I turn something like that into PDF? I should also note that any editing I apply in this library can cause the application to crash whenever I visit a scan page. The web application also comes with library Kramdown-1.4.1, which has some sort of PDF converter; but I am honestly not sure if it's the most ideal tool to use. I have looked up countless sources, and this does not seem to be a known issue to many.